# Windows Backup has detected that disk might be corrupted

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, backup

I am trying to backup my VirtualBox windows 10 to my external hard drive with Windows 10 backup tool. (Control Panel/Backup and Restore)

- This tool tells me that my disk has a problem.

[image]

- Then I try to check that problem with Right click to the Local E Properties/Tools Tab/Error Checking. I got this message:

[image]

The detailed error log is here:

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on E:

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

  1423872 file records processed.                                                         
File verification completed.

  1333 large file records processed.                                                                                                                           
  0 bad file records processed.                                      
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x8b5fbf7000 for 0x200 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x8b5fbf7000 for 0x200 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x8b5fbf7000 for 0x200 bytes.
Unable to setup the attribute list in file 0x14e63.
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x8b5fbf7000 for 0x200 bytes.
An unspecified error occurred (6672732e637878 5e0).
```

My main operating system is Ubuntu.So give a try with Linux tools to check disk problems.

**Bad Sector Checking**
* First I checked the bad sectors with the following command, no bad sector is found
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb > /home/q/badsectors

**Note:** I have no problem with using this disk on Linux Ubuntu. I can also back up my computer to this external disk successfully every day with CloneZilla.I think my windows 10 or my VirtualBox is problematic not my hard drive.

My virtual box version:`5.2.18r124319`

**Note:** I think that the problem is related to the defragmentation of the disk.Because tool has issues with some addresses such as between like 0xc0000185 at offset 0x8b5fbf7000 (Look up to the my windows disk error check log)

*Extra Note:* I cannot find a good title for this question.Sorry for that.

Comment: That may be a "content error" rather than a surface defect, so it doesn't show up as a bad sector.  Chkdsk could be unable to repair it because it has no way to know what the correct information should be, and there's too much corruption for the error correcting code to fix.  It looks like the error is in the directory information rather than the file content, so the data may be recoverable.  You might be able to use a low level recovery tool like Recuva to scrape the file contents.

Comment: Why do I need to recover files of the hard drive? I have no problem with data of the disk.

Comment: The error message indicates that there are some files the computer no longer knows how to find even though their content is still there.  Recovery software may be able to do it.  If you can account for every file that should be there, the error message might apply to something that was deleted, so no longer relevant.  In that case, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your external drive, not with your Windows disk.

I suggest to save any data you have on that drive and reformat it to fix the
corruption.

I also suggest to use another tool than the problematic Windows Backup.
I warmly recommend [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).